# trigger an event by clicking on an anchor element which is inserted by Handlebars

Tags: javascript, jquery, handlebars.js

Okay, let's say I append the below anchor element with handlebars.
I want to trigger an event after I click on it. However, after I insert it, javascript events don't work on it. Here is what I mean:

```
<div class="list-group" id="listGroup">
    <a class="list-group-item" href="#" name="jumanji">JUMANJI</a>
    <a class="list-group-item active" href="#" name="looper">LOOPER</a>
    <a class="list-group-item" href="#" name="lone_survivor">LONE SURVIVOR</a>
    <a class="list-group-item" href="#" name="the_dark_knight">THE DARK KNIGHT</a>
    <a class="list-group-item" href="#" name="world_war_z">WORLD WAR Z</a>
    <script id="list" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
        {{#fill this}}
        <a class="list-group-item" id="joe" href="#">{{name}}</a>
        {{/fill}}
        </script>
</div>
```

After I insert the last anchor element with handlebars, I want to trigger an event by clicking on it, for example:

```
$('#joe').click(function () { alert ("hi"); }
```

But it is like joe doesn't exist, however, I can reach joe by clicking something else and referencing it from there. Let's say there is another element with the id "moe", then I can do this.

```
$('#moe').click(function () { alert($('#joe').html()); }
```

Hope I made myself clear, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try the event delegation using **[on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)** function:

```
$(document).on('click','#joe',function () { alert ("hi"); }
```

Comment: thanks that works, does document.on re-render the document? Also another question, why do I need deep-linking and states for my application, does it have anything to do with the question I asked?

Comment: actually **$(document).on()** listens for events for the dynamically added elements, while the **click()** function as you said gets rendered at the initiation moment, therefore finds no matching element. so for dynamically added elements you always have to delegate the events.

Comment: and about your question, I don't understand what you mean by "deep-linking and states"?